# Different font size and color using CSS for data retrieved via JSTL

Tags: html, css, jsp, jstl

I am working on a web application where I get some string data using Java Servlets and then subsequently display that data on a JSP view using JSTL. Below is the code snippet:

```
    <table border="1" width=100%>
<th style="width: 10%">S. NUMBER</th>
<th style="width:35%"> First Name </th>
<th style="width: 35%"> Second Name </th>
<th style="width: 10%">Student ID</th>
<th style="width: 10%">Student Class</th>
<c:forEach items="${sortedResults}" var="result">
    <tr>
        <td>${result.counter}</td>
        <td>${result.sequenceIntEx}</td>
        <td>${result.lName}</td>
        <td>${result.sID}</td>
        <td>${result.sClass}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

For example, the lName field, i want to display the 3rd and 4th characters in a bigger font size with different color. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps assign systematic element names ex. id="td1" id="td2" etc. and then use jsp to generate a css file that matches the automatic element names and filling in any parameters needed depending on your criteria.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I got it working. I am will post the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

So, i got this working using substring functions in JSTL. First, the following needs to be imported:

```
   <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
```

Then, i used the substrings to do the needed formatting.

```
    <td>${fn:substring(result.sequenceIntEx, 0, 3)}<font size="5" color="red">${fn:substring(result.sequenceIntEx, 3, 5)}</font>${fn:substring(result.sequenceIntEx, 5, 13)}</td>
```

Thanks